# Putty + Firefox Gives Blank Screen

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

Completely new to this, so please bear with me.

I have been using a VPS with HG for a few months, other than needing the extra resources to deal with loads I haven't used it much. Anyway... I am trying to set up a private proxy with the VPS, after hours of looking into this it seems Putty is the best option for me, every tutorial I read has the same process and when they say 'that's it!', it never seems to be it.

I can successfully connect via Putty and have even gone as far as connecting automatically for the profile with keys, I have also assigned and saved a Dynamic Source Port.

I can connect automatically no problem with everything in this profile, here's my problem.

First off, would I be safe to assume I start Putty and load this profile and run it to use the private proxy?

Second, I have tried configuring FF and FoxyProxy with the necessary proxy settings i.e. 127.0.0.1:1234 (assuming 1234 was the Dynamic Port set earlier), when I try visiting a web page I get no error, but I just get a blank screen, does anyone know what this problem is?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue where the radio button in the FoxyProxy "Proxy details" tab for "SOCKS v5" was selected but I was getting the blank screen.. then I noticed a checkbox to the left for "SOCKS proxy?".  After checking that box my configuration started working.